# Order of operations with JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/h6nh1gvw/1/ . I'm not experienced with JS.

I see that ;

```
alert(JSON.stringify(getCarData()[0]));
```

produces :

```
{"car":"Mercedes A 160","year":2006,"available":true,"comesInBlack":"yes"}
```

but:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(getCarData())[0]);
```

produces:

```
[
```

Could someone explain in plain english what is happening here? Intuitively I feel that the second operation should work in producing the first JSON record as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between the two orders of operations, which I will explain below.

**TLDR**
The first call to JSON.stringify() you do gets the car data you want and then stringifies it, while the second way stringifies an array of objects containing car data and then tries to access the first element in that string, which is the first character of that string.

**Let's break down what the following line is doing:**

```
alert(JSON.stringify(getCarData()[0]));
```

First

```
getCarData()
```

returns and Array that has an object in it at position 0. The [0] is saying give me the first item from the array of car data returned by getCarData().

You then pass this object to the JSON.stringify() function to be stringified. This works as you expect returning:

```
{"car":"Mercedes A 160","year":2006,"available":true,"comesInBlack":"yes"}
```

**The second stringify call you make:**

```
alert(JSON.stringify(getCarData())[0]);
```

is getting the car data (which is returned as an array) and passing it to the JSON.stringify function.

```
JSON.stringify(getCarData())
```

This will return an array of objects containing car data. JSON then tries to stringify the array, and returns

```
[{"car":"Mercedes A 160","year":2006,"available":true,"comesInBlack":"yes"},{"car":"Citroen C4 Coupe","year":2008,"available":false,"comesInBlack":"yes"},{"car":"Audi A4 Avant","year":2011,"available":true,"comesInBlack":"no"},{"car":"Opel Astra","year":2004,"available":false,"comesInBlack":"yes"},{"car":"BMW 320i Coupe","year":2011,"available":false,"comesInBlack":"no"}]
```

Next you try to access the first item in this stringified array, but since it is now a string (not an array) it just returns [, the first character of the string.

**In conclusion**

The first way you do it gets the data you want and then stringifies it, while the second way stringiness an array of objects containing car data and then tries to access the first element in a string, which is the first character of that string.

Answer (score 2):

In your first line of code you provide you are serializing an object and getting the result as a JSON string. The second example it seems you were trying to treat that object as an array and serialize the first element of that array that comes back.

Assuming this is the case you need to alter the location of the parenthesis in your code to be:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(getCarData()[0]));
```

What you wrote will actually just take the first character from the JSON string returned (which is "["). Hence the output that you get from this.

One other thing that is noteworthy here though is the fact that you aren't going to get what you expect when you index an object. You probably should specify a property name that you hope to serialize, something like:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(getCarData()["car"]));
```

You get the point. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `JSON.stringify` doesn't throw an error, the result of `JSON.stringify(foo)` is a *String*, let's call this `str`, so

```
JSON.stringify(getCarData())[0];
// same as
JSON.stringify(foo)[0]; // foo = getCarData()
// same as
str[0];
```

So by using the `[0]` here you're getting the first character from a *String*. This will be a `"["` if you've *stringified* an *Array*

---

Now we understand this, let's look back at `JSON.stringify(foo[0])`, assuming `foo` is *Array-like*.

The `[0]` here is selecting the item at index `0` of the array, let's call this `item`, so

```
JSON.stringify(getCarData()[0]);
// same as
JSON.stringify(foo[0]); // foo = getCarData()
// same as
JSON.stringify(item);
// so we end up with
str2; // not the same as str
```

This time we have *stringified* something from *JavaScript* but not done anything further, so the result is the *JSON* representation of whatever we called *stringify* on (in your case it was an *Object*)

Answer (score 2):

`getCarData()` is an array of objects.

`getCarData()[0]` is the first object of this array of objects, so it can be stringified.

`JSON.stringify(getCarData()[0])` will return a string of the the first object of the array of objects.

`JSON.stringify(getCarData())` will return a **string** of the entire array of objects.

`JSON.stringify(getCarData())[0]` will return the first letter of the string produced by the above command, which is `[`, because you're essentially doing something like `"hi"[0]` which is a character, whereas previously you did `{"hi","hello"}[0]` which is a string element.

Comment: By the result of `JSON.stringify`, it looks like `getCarData()` returns an _Array_ of _Objects_

Answer (score 2):

Lets break down what `alert(JSON.stringify(getCarData())[0]);` is trying to do.

Remeber PEMDAS? We are basically doing the same thing.

1. The deepest parenthesis call is `getCarData()`, which returns the array.
2. Next, you call `JSON.stringify()` on that array, which returns a string.
3. And finally, you call `[0]`, which effectively grabs the first character of that string.